# Elementary proof that one cannot cover a unit disk with countably many curves

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces, alternative-proof

Consider $\mathbb{D} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ denote the unit disk. We call a function $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{D}$ that is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ a **curve**. Consider the following question:

> Is it possible to cover $\mathbb{D}$ with countably many curves? That is, do there exist a countably family of curves $\{\gamma_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that $\mathbb{D} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{ran}(\gamma_n)$?

This problem can be easily solved using measure theory: The (Lebesgue) measure of $\mathbb{D}$ is positive, while the measure of each curve is $0$, so $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{ran}(\gamma_n)$ also has measure zero by $\sigma$-additivity. Hence such a family of curve does not exist. (Note also that as remarked by @freakish in his comment, the condition for $\gamma_n$'s being differentiable is necessary)

I would like to know if there is a proof of this using elementary analysis methods. As a reference, I wish to restrict the methods used in the proof to Chapter 1-3 of baby Rudin (and if possible, as little topology as possible).

Comment: Unlikely. Note that without the "differentiable" assumption this actually is true, even for a single (space-filling) curve. One of the reasons differentiability is important is because such curves cannot be "thick".

Comment: Since each such curve is nowhere dense, one can use a Baire category argument. The most problematic aspect of this for your restrictions is coming up with the idea of "nowhere dense" (in this form: every nonempty open interval contains a nonempty open interval that is disjoint from the set), because the Baire category argument then becomes a natural generalization of the Cantor nested-interval argument for uncountability of the reals (e.g. as done on pp. 1-2 of Oxtoby's [**Measure and Category**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387905081)).

Comment: *(in this form: every nonempty open interval contains a nonempty open interval that is disjoint from the set)* --- "open interval" should be "open ball", since we're in ${\mathbb R}^2.$ Incidentally, as for why the graph of a differentiable curve is nowhere dense, it follows immediately from local linearity.